# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module 'restore-cursor'

Tags: angular

Has anyone seen this issue in Angular 11 - ng serve?

> Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\x\Desktop\codebase\app\node_modules\cli-cursor\index.js
> - C:\Users\x\Desktop\codebase\app\node_modules\ora\index.js
> - C:\Users\x\Desktop\codebase\app\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\spinner.js
> - C:\Users\x\Desktop\codebase\app\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\i18n-inlining.js
> - C:\Users\x\Desktop\codebase\app\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
> - C:\Users\x\Desktop\codebase\app\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
> - C:\Users\x\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng

Comment: I've tried cleaning node_modules, npm cache clean --force etc but no luck

Comment: Did you update or change any version? When did you encounter it like after installing some packages or update?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to upgrade 1 package. It didn't upgraded. After that I've tried to updated Angular CLI to  latest 11 minor version.

Comment: Now I am back to original state, but this error just doesn't go away. I've installed 'restore-cursor' package but 'ng serve' complaints this now: An unhandled exception occurred: require() of ES Module C:\Users\x\Desktop\codebase\app\node_modules\restore-cursor\index.js from C:\Users\x\Desktop\codebase\app\node_modules\cli-cursor\index.js not supported.

Comment: It seems there is a version mismatch. Have you tried to install the previous stable version of `restore-cursor`?

Comment: ah it worked, that's strange. Do you know any reason why Angular expects 'restore-cursor' to be installed explicitly?

Comment: Let me put it in the answer for future reference. Its generally due to mismatch of peer dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such issues are very common due to the version mismatch. When it occurs try to move back to the previous stable version and make sure all other versions should match with the other peer-dependencies.

Try to explicitly install `restore-cursor` :

```
npm i restore-cursor@last-stable-version-number --save
```